# Export Page from pages lose all web parts

Tags: web-part

I'm exporting a Test.aspx from Pages by Sharepoint Designer -> All Files -> Test.aspx -> Export File

After that I import the file and all web parts are gone.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`Page` and `Web Part` are two different components in SharePoint. When you export a page, it only exports the page data i.e. what page contains. It never exports the component of page, like web part, layouts etc. based on which a page display content.

In order to confirm if your page is containing all web parts, you add `?contenst=1` query string to your page. The page which will open know as `Web Part Maintenance Page`, where all the web part are listed in page.

I think your page contains custom web part, which are not accessible to you. In such case, you can deploy the solution to other site collection where you are importing the page and your page will render them.